# Property Injection does not work when using RegisterApiControllers extension method

Tags: c#, owin, autofac, webapi

Consider my simple controller class where I want to use a logger (ILogger is coming from Castle in this case).

```
[RoutePrefix("api/orders")]
public class SignalController : ApiController
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; } = new NullLogger();

    // POST api/orders/update
    [HttpPost, Route("update")]
    public virtual void UpdateHandler(ChangeStateDto update)
    {
        this.Logger.Info($"Received ChangeStateDto with status {update.Status}");
    }
}
```

Then I've got a self-hosted webhost, that looks like this.

```
public class WebHost
{
    private readonly string url;
    private IDisposable disposable;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope scope;

    public WebHost(string url, ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; } = new NullLogger();

    // ...

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Logger.Info($"Starting web host at {url}");
            this.disposable = WebApp.Start(this.url, app =>
            {
                var config = new HttpConfiguration
                {
                    DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(scope)
                };

                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                app.UseWebApi(config);
            });

            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ...
            this.Logger.Error(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the calling type

```
public class SomeCallerClass
{
    public SomeCallerClass()
    {
        var webHostLogger = new SomeILoggerImplementation(this, "WebHost");

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers()
               .WithProperty("Logger", webHostLogger);
        var container = builder.Build();
            
        this.webHost = new WebHost("http://localhost:9000", container)
        {
            Logger = webHostLogger
        };
    }
}
```

Now the issue I am having is that property injection is not working for my `SignalController` type. It always holds a reference to the `NullLogger` instance. I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *solved* it by using `.RegisterType<>` instead of `.RegisterApiControllers`

So the following works as expected. However I still don't understand why my first approach wasn't working.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SignalController>()
    .WithProperty("Logger", webHostLogger)
    .InstancePerRequest();

var container = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably wasn't working because it wasn't registering any controllers.

In your code you have:

```cs
builder
  .RegisterApiControllers()
  .WithProperty("Logger", webHostLogger);
```

However, you have to tell the registration extension which assemblies your controllers are in. [You can see that in the examples shown in the docs.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html)

Try:

```cs
builder
  .RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
  .WithProperty("Logger", webHostLogger);
```

Comment: Thx for replying. But than why was the controller instanciated and useable?

Comment: Likely fell back to the parameterless constructor. Did this fix the problem? If so, can it be accepted as the answer?